# Java , to change the iso date format to required format

Tags: java, angularjs, mongodb

I need to convert the current ISO Date to the required format . How ?
Mongodb iso date: 2016-08-31T08:30:17.795Z

required format type: Aug 31,2016 08:30 AM

Comment: Okay, so there are hundreds of questions about parsing and reformatting dates in Java... what have you tried so far, and what happened?

Comment: how about trying the search function? -> http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+format+date

Answer (score 0):

I think it is recommended to store date as ISO format into the database. If you want to display on the client side with AngularJS. Just initial a new date object as below.

```
var date = new Date('2016-08-31T08:30:17.795Z')
```

It will return as

```
Wed Aug 31 2016 16:30:17 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)
```

And after that, you can use some built-in function to extract date, time or hour like

```
date.getDate()  
date.getSeconds()
```

And next time please search on StackOverflow first because there are a lot of answer for this kind of question :D

Refer [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

**Date conversion:**

parse the date

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss",   Locale.ENGLISH);
```

For formatting in your date

```
DateFormat formatterWithTime = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,YYYY HH:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(formatterWithTime.format(formatter.parse("2016-08-31T08:30:17.795Z")));
```

> Output : Aug 31,2016 08:30 AM

Comment: It worked ,Thanks for the help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using the mongo java driver, you do **not** have to supply the date in a given (string-) format. Instead, you simply use java.util.Date objects.